# Is it more secure to hash a password multiple times?

Tags: hashing

I've read a few times that when storing passwords, it's good practice to 'double hash' the strings (eg. with md5 then sha1, both with salts, obviously).

I guess the first question is, "is this actually correct?" If not, then please, dismiss the rest of this question :)

The reason I ask is that on the face of it, I would say that this makes sense. However, when I think about it, every time a hash is rehashed (possibly with something added to it) all I can see is that there is a reduction in the upper bound on the final 'uniqueness'... that bound being related to the initial input.

Let me put it another way: we have x number of strings that, when hashed, are reduced to y possible strings. That is to say, there are collisions in the first set. Now coming from the second set to the third, is it not possible for the same thing to occur (ie. collisions in the set of all possible 'y' strings that result in the same hash in the third set)?

In my head, all I see is a 'funnel' for each hash function call, 'funneling' an infinite set of possibilities into a finite set and so on, but obviously each call is working on the finite set before it, giving us a set no larger than the input.

Maybe an example will explain my ramblings?
Take 'hash_function_a' that will give 'a' and 'b' the hash '1', and will give 'c' and 'd' the hash '2'. Using this function to store passwords, even if the password is 'a', I could use the password 'b'.

Take 'hash_function_b' that will give '1' and '2' the hash '3'. If I were to use *it* as a 'secondary hash' after 'hash_function_a' then even if the password is 'a' I could use 'b', 'c' or 'd'.

On top of all of that, I get that salts should be used, but they don't really change the fact that each time we are mapping 'x' inputs to 'less than x' outputs. I don't think.

Can someone please explain to me what it is that I am missing here?

Thanks!

EDIT: for what it's worth, I don't do this myself, I use bcrypt. And I'm not really concerned about whether or not it's useful for 'using up cycles' for a 'hacker'. I genuinely am just wondering whether or not the process reduces 'security' from a hash collision stand point.

Comment: @S.Lott: I don't really see how that answers the actual question, though... all it says is either "don't do it yourself, use this thing" or "it's good to take up time!"... neither of which answer "is it actually more secure". Again, unless I'm missing something.

Comment: @MetalMikester: Yeah, that was yesterday's article: http://thedailywtf.com/Articles/Bulletproof-Encryption.aspx

Comment: This isn't on-topic for IT Security, but it does look like a good match for Cryptography. In fact, it looks extremely similar to [this question there](http://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/270/guarding-against-cryptanalytic-breakthroughs-combining-multiple-hash-functions).

Comment: I know of a company that wanted to use unsalted `MD5(password)`. We said it's not secure, so they suggested using `MD5(MD5(password))` instead...

Comment: The accepted answer is not the correct answer!

Comment: Hashing multiple times _with the same algorithm_ takes time. This limits the rate at which an attacker can guess passwords. For example the passcode on an iPhone is hashed so many times that it takes 80 milliseconds to check it. Which limits an attacker to 1 million guesses per day. (Faster iPhones hash more often so that the time is always 80 milliseconds, no matter what the speed of the phone is).

Answer (score 30, accepted):

This is more suited on security.stackexchange but...

The problem with

```
hash1(hash2(hash3(...hashn(pass+salt)+salt)+salt)...)+salt)
```

is that this is only as strong as the weakest hash function in the chain. For example if hashn (the innermost hash) gives a collision, the entire hash chain will give a collision (*irrespective of what other hashes are in the chain*).

A stronger chain would be

```
hash1(hash2(hash3(...hashn(pass + salt) + pass + salt) + pass + salt)...) + pass + salt)
```

Here we avoid the early collision problem and we essentially generate a salt that depends on the password for the final hash.

And if one step in the chain collides it doesn't matter because in the next step the password is used again and should give a different result for different passwords.

Comment: So right now I see that adding "password + salt" as the salt to the next round of hashing might be increasing the amount of 'stuff' that could go into the funnel, now I just have to understand by 'how much'. Thanks.

Comment: Actually I think I do get it now: by forcing the password into each layer of the hashing, is it actually reducing the number of possible collisions by essentially requiring 'the colliding password' and the real password to have matching hashes across each 'call', right? I'm thinking that I was missing the 'put the password in at each layer' part! Thanks again.

Comment: @Narcissus no prob and that also has the bonus of allowing weaker inner hashes (as long as the outer/final hashes are strong) as the inner hashes are just generating the salt for the next pass

Comment: hum, I think that the problem is a bit bigger (and deeper) than that. With rainbow attacks, you can just generate tables considering all your hashes, and the problem remains.

Comment: I'll agree that is is not more secure than a strong hash and a long random salt but it avoids the naive "let's run the hash through the hasher again and be more secure" while that is *less* secure

Comment: @woliveirajr: again, I'm not wondering about "how long it takes to crack" or anything like that... my question is about whether or not it is adding more security or is actually making it less secure *in and of itself*.

Comment: @Narcissus: in a very short answer: Yes, it's not *more* secure. Yes, probably it's even *less* secure.

Comment: @Narcissus: Naively repeating a hashing algorithm without introducing any new data does, obviously and unarguably, reduce the total amount of entropy in the system. That is, in essence, what a hashing algorithm *does*, reduce a very large or infinite input space into a much smaller output space via a non-random but unpredictable mapping. The real question here is is that even significant? If your output space is still `2^256` bits large, then while repeated hashing does shrink that space, it's still absolutely massive and brute force attacks are still completely non-viable.

Comment: Suppose one uses this strategy and stores the hashes in a database, which is then compromised.  To retrieve possible passwords from the stronger chain, an attacker only needs to reverse hash1.  So, this algorithm is probably not a good choice for key-strengthening.

Comment: @brian the entire chain indeed depends on strength of the last hash applied

Comment: One thing I'm curious about is using multiple hashing that interact with each other and are a part of the end result.  Not so much as hash1(hash2(pass+salt)) but hash=hash1(hash+pass+salt)+hash2(hash+pass+salt) with several hundred iterations. Appending the hashes allows the ability to reduce collisions.  If they were not appending the calculated hashes within itself, it would be as simple as breaking one hash, and testings those breaks with the other hash until a match is found.

Comment: @JeremyWalton except when you have an few utterly broken hashes where you can derive large parts of the input, and because they are all included in the output each hash can be attacked separately.

Answer (score 59):

Using different hashing algorithms is a bad idea - it will reduce entropy rather than increase it.

However, assuming you have a cryptographically strong hashing algorithm and a good salt, applying *the same hash function* several times makes the hashing process more computationally expensive. The benefit of this is that when other means of cracking the password hash fail (guessing, dictionary attacks, rainbow tables, etc.), and the attacker is forced into brute-force techniques, it takes them longer to try each password, simply because they have to apply the same hash function more often. So if one round of hashing would require one month of brute-forcing, applying it twelve times would increase the estimated time to a year.

Recent hashing algorithms like bcrypt build on this idea; they contain a parameter to control the computational complexity of the hash, so that you can scale it as hardware speeds progress: when hardware becomes faster by a factor of two, you increase the complexity to compensate, so the time required to brute-force your hashes remains roughly constant.

Comment: This is the correct answer!

Comment: @markus: as per the discussion that I read, this is only correct because of the addition "and a good salt" which is addressed by the accepted answer, isn't it? Why is this one correct and the accepted answer not?

Comment: It is the correct answer because the only reason for applying the same hashing function multiple times (parameterized) is that you can use this iteration to adjust for faster hardware. Otherwise there is no benefit from hashing multiple times.

Comment: @Narcissus The key here is entropy. There's a difference between hashing many times using the same method versus hashing many times using different methods.

Answer (score 3):

Do not try to write your own password hashing scheme unless your are willing to take a course in cryptography and/or security engineering.

You should use a well established implementation of password hashing which in turn should use a key derivation function ([KDF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Key_derivation_function)) such as PBKDF2, bcrypt, scrypt or the newer Argon2.

Good KDFs include a workfactor, usually a number of iterations, in order to increase the cost of offline attacks. One could say that these KDFs hash the password multiple times, using the same algorithm each time. There is no point in using multiple message digest algorithm, as pointed out by others.

Comment: the link [https://crackstation.net/hashing-security.htm](https://crackstation.net/hashing-security.htm) is blocked by firewall

Comment: @gnat For some reason, I had missed your comment regarding the blocked URL. I have replaced  it with a link to wikipedia.

Answer (score 2):

In general, you don't need to use more than one hashing algorithm.

What you need to do is:

Use salt: salt isn't used just to make your password *more secure*, it's used to aboid rainbow table attack. That way, someone will have a harder work trying to precompute the hash for passwords you store in your system.

Use multiple interations: instead of doing just SHA(password + salt), do SHA(SHA(SHA(SHA(SHA(...SHA( password + salt )))))) . Or, to represent in other way:

```
hash = sha(password + salt)
for i=1 , i=5000, i++ {
    hash = sha(hash + salt);
}
```

And, finally, choose a good hashing function. SHA, MD5, etc, are not good because they are too *fast*. Since you want to use hash for protection, you'd better use slower hashes. Take a look at [Bcrypt](http://www.usenix.org/events/usenix99/provos/provos_html/index.html), [PBKDF2](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PBKDF2) or [Scrypt](http://www.tarsnap.com/scrypt.html), for example.

**edit**: after observations, let's try to see some points (sorry, long explanation to get to the end, because it might help others searching for similar answers):

If your system is secure, like no one will ever ever get access to the stored password, you wouldn't need hash. The password would be secret, no one would get it.

*But* no one can assure that the database with the passwords will be stolen. Steal the database, got all the passwords. Ok, your system and your company will suffer all the consequences of it. So, we could try to avoid this password leaking.

*NOTICE*  that we are not worried about online attacks in this point. For one online attack, the best solution is to slow down after bad passwords, lock the account after some tries, etc. And for that it doesn't matter which way you encrypt, hash, store, etc, your password. Online attack is a matter of *slowing down the password inputs*.

So, back to the `don't let them take my plain passwords` problem. The answer is simple: don't store them as plain text. Ok, got it.

How to avoid that?

Encrypt the password (?). But, as you know, if you encrypt it, you can decrypt it back, if you have the proper key. And you'll end up with the problem of "where to hide" the key. Hum, no good, since they got you database, they can get your key. Ok, let's not use it.

So, another approach: let's transform the password in something else that can't be reversed and store it. And to verify if the supplied password is correct, we do the same process again and check if the two tranformed values match. If they match = the good password was supplied.

Ok, so far so good. Let's use some MD5 hash in the password. But... if someone has our stored hashed value of password, he can have a lot of computer power to calculate the MD5 hash of every possible password (brute force), so he can find the original password. Or, even worst, he can store all the MD5 from all characteres combinations, and easily find the password. So, do a lot of iteractions, the HASH(HASH(HASH())) thing, to make it harder, because it'll take more time.

But even that can be circunvented, the rainbow table was created exactly to speed up against this kind of protection.

So, let's use some salt over it. This way, at each interaction, the salt is used again. One trying to attack your passwords will have to generate the rainbow table considering that the salt is added each time. And when he generates that rainbow table, since it was generated with one salt, he'll have to calculate again with the other salt, so he will have to spend some time for each password (=each salt). Salt won't add "more complexity" to the password, it'll just make the attacker loose time generating the rainbow table, if you use one salt for each password, the table from one salt is useless to another password.

And using more than one hash will have helped here? No. The person generating a specific rainbow attack will be able to generate it using one or more hashes, anyway.

And using more than one hash can lead you to one problem: it's as secure as the weakest hash you use. If someone find collisions in one hash algorithm, it's that hash that will be exploited, at any point of the the iteration process, to break the password. So, you don't gain anything by using more hashes algorithms, it's better to choose just one good algo. and use it. And if yuo ever hear that it has been broken, think how you'll change it in your application.

And why use bcrypt or something like that (you say you use it): because the attacker will have to spend more time generating the tables. That's why using MD5 + wait (3 seconds) doesn't help: the attack will be offline, anyway, so the attacker can generate the tables without the (3 seconds delay).

Comment: WRT point 3: The bestest hashing algorithms take a "timeout" parameter so you can choose how slow they will be. ;)

Comment: @Frustrated : updated answer... no, timeout won't be of much help in the situation

Comment: Oops! Sorry, my comment (about deliberately making the hash slower via timeout parameter) wasn't meant to be taken seriously...  I think I've been reading too much Dilbert lately.

Comment: sha(sha(sha( . . . ))) isn't more secure than sha. If the entropy of sha function isn't maximal, this is actually less secure.

Comment: @deadalnix: it's important to mention that it doesn't make it easier to recover the original password, but it does make it easier to generate a colliding password, which is all that's required.

Comment: @deadalnix, I read that comment in the voice of [Dale Gribble](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cJbDnQWPLhg).

Comment: @deadalnix: the goal of sha(sha(sha())) isn't, and never were, to add more entropy. Entropy is just made by the initial user choosing his password, everything else (hash, salt, etc) is just to slow down a brute-force attack. If someone is able to get your database containing the passwords, he probably will get the code used to hash the password as well, so any hard-coded salt is also known

Comment: @woliveirajr > The point of the salt is to generate entropy (because user generated password has weak entropy and will eventually fail with lookup table). The multiple hash will just reduce entropy (or, if sha is proven to has the maximal entropy, which isn't proven and probably not true), so this will be easier to generate a collision. You know, if you are not competent to anwer, you don't have to. That may sound harsh (and it is) but this is the worse behaviour you can have. Giving false informations is veen worse than giving no information at all.

Comment: @deadalnix: don't get mad, I'd love to learn more. Could you send me links pointing out why salt is used? Buy I mean academic articles, not just wikipedia pages...

Comment: @deadalnix: also, if salt is concerned to entropy, why not we just obly users to choose better passwords?

Comment: @woliveirajr > I could answer that, but this is not the point of comments. I suggest you ask the question as we are in a question website. Thoses questions are interesting, so no doubt it's worth ask them !

Comment: @woliveirajr: If you store a million hashed passwords, a hacker trying a password can check whether it matches any of the one million hashed passwords without any additional effort. Using a salt, he can only check whether it matches one particular hashed password with the right salt. So the cracking effort is a million times higher.

Answer (score -1):

My understanding is that using multiple hashing algorithms is to defeat [rainbow tables](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rainbow_table). Using a good salt works too, but I guess it's a second level of protection.

Comment: Well this doesn't change that much. The « multiple hash » fucntion can be seen as one and treated as such.

Comment: Using multiple hashing techniques or iterations does nothing to defeat rainbow tables. If an attacker has your database, and has the method used to generate the hashes, the attacker can then generate a rainbow table to attack all the passwords in the database. SALTS prevent rainbow table attacks as they prevent the attacker from generating a single lookup dictionary to attack, say, all passwords of 8 characters or less.

Answer (score -1):

This isn't more secure. However, you have a protocol of identification based on hash multiple times with the same function.

This goes that way. The stored value is hash^n(pass) in computer A. A ask B to authentify and gives B the integer n. B does the calculation hash^(n-1)(pass) and send it back to A.

A check that hash(hash^(n-1)(pass)) == hash^n(pass) . If it is true, then the authentification is done. But then, A store hash^(n-1)(pass) and next authentification, will give B n-1 instead of n.

This ensure that the password is never exchanged in clear, that A never knows what the password is, and that authentification is protected by replay. However, this has the drawback to require password with a finite lifetime. When n reach the value 2, a new password must be choosen after authentification.

Another use of multiple hash is the tool HMAC, to ensure authentification and integrity of a request. For more about HMAC see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HMAC .

Most usage of multiple hash in the real world are overkill. In your case, it seems to be. Note that if you use several hash functions, they will not all have the same entropy, thus this reduce the strengh of the hash. For exemple, md5 has less entropy than sha1, so using sha1 on an md5 will not improve the strength of the hash. The strengh will generally be equal to the strength of the weaker hash function.